# SparkSQL Query performance improvement by CLUSTER By

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I am new to `SparkSQL` and I primarily work with writing `SparkSQL` queries. We often need to `JOIN` big tables in the queries and it did not take long to face performance issues pertaining to them (eg. `Joins`, `aggregates` etc).

While searching for remedies online, I recently came across the terms - `COALESCE()`, `REPARTITION()`, `DISTRIBUTE BY`, `CLUSTER BY` etc and the fact that they could probably be used for **enhancing** performance of slow running `SparkSQL` **queries**.

Unfortunately, I could not find enough examples around, for me to understand them clearly and start applying them to my queries. I am primarily looking for examples explaining their syntax, hints and usage scenarios.

Can anyone please help me out here and provide `SparkSQL` query examples of their usage and when to use them ? E.g.

- syntax
- hint syntax
- tips
- scenarios

Note: I only have access to writing `SparkSQL` Queries but **don't** have access to `PySpark-SQL`.

Any help is much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**coalesce**

coalesce(expr1, expr2, ...) - Returns the first non-null argument if exists. Otherwise, null.

Examples:

> SELECT coalesce(NULL, 1, NULL);
> 1
> Since: 1.0.0

**Distribute By and REPARTITION**

Repartitions a DataFrame by the given expressions. The number of partitions is equal to spark.sql.shuffle.partitions. Note that in Spark, when a DataFrame is partitioned by some expression, all the rows for which this expression is equal are on the same partition (but not necessarily vice-versa)!
This is how it looks in practice. Let’s say we have a DataFrame with two columns: key and value.

> SET spark.sql.shuffle.partitions = 2 
> SELECT * FROM df DISTRIBUTE BY key 
> Equivalent in DataFrame API:
>
> df.repartition($"key", 2)

**Cluster By**

This is just a shortcut for using distribute by and sort by together on the same set of expressions.
In SQL:

> SET spark.sql.shuffle.partitions = 2 
> SELECT * FROM df CLUSTER BY key